# Javafx: Bringing two points closer to each other with angle

Tags: java, math, javafx

Hello to all Stackoverflow users, I have Polygon shape (or triangle shapes) that I need added some Label into it center of side , Imagine I have Frame That if clip the shape remove other area from it, the problem is if clip the label of my GraphicContext will removed from shape that I created, In order to said about the problem I had I want labels goes to near center of shape with some gap I added to it(like 24px 72px etc...) but I found it if I want to do that need culc the angle and add ratio into gap to closed into center , but I don't know How can do this? my mathematic is poor :)) can anyone give me a tip?

The shape that I added is just example of what I need , and the code that I show you just some dirty work.

[image]

[image]

```
         private int[] pointLocateForExportLabel(Point2D a1, Point2D a2, Point2D centerPoint, int fontMetric) {
        int gapIntoShape = (int) (fontMetric) * 9;
        App.logger.debug("The Center point : " + centerPoint);
        App.logger.debug("The A1 of point : " + a1);
        App.logger.debug("The A2 of point : " + a2);
        App.logger.debug("==============================");
        int poX = (int) (((a1.getX() + a2.getX()) / 2));
        int poY = (int) (((a1.getY() + a2.getY()) / 2));
        Point c1 = new Point(poX, poY);
        double deltaX = centerPoint.getX() - c1.getX();
        double deltaY = centerPoint.getY() - c1.getY();
        double coeff = 0.05;
        Point2D c = null;
        if (centerPoint.getX() > c1.getX()) {
            c = new Point2D(c1.getX() + coeff * deltaX, c1.getY() + coeff * deltaY);
        } else {
            c = new Point2D((c1.getX() + coeff * deltaX) - gapIntoShape, c1.getY() + coeff * deltaY);
        }
        return new int[]{(int) c.getX(), (int) c.getY()};
    }
```

Update :
For better understanding , I need bring close point into near the other point! but not for one direction (just x or y) in two direction(x and y), it's simple problem that IDK how too fixed.

[image]

Comment: You can calculate the [centroid using commons geometry](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-geometry/commons-geometry-euclidean/apidocs/org/apache/commons/geometry/euclidean/twod/Vector2D.html#centroid-org.apache.commons.geometry.euclidean.twod.Vector2D-org.apache.commons.geometry.euclidean.twod.Vector2D...-).  Once you have that you can calculate the midpoint of a side and interpolate a point along a line between the centroid and side midpoint.

Comment: The correct solution (IMO) would be to create a Scalable Vector Graphic (SVG)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Point2D`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/geometry/Point2D.html) class implements a lot of basic vector algebra operations.

Mathematically, if `a` and `b` are points, then `b-a` represents the vector from `a` to `b`. For a scalar `t`,

```
a + t(b-a) = (1-t)a + tb
```

represents a point on the line passing through `a` and `b` (intuitively, start at `a` and move some multiple of the vector from `a` to `b`). When `t=0`, `(1-t)a +tb = a` and when `t=1`, `(1-t)a + tb = b`.

In your case, `a` is the center point of the line, `b` is the center of the shape, and `t` is the value you called `coeff` in your code.

So in Java code this just looks like:

```
Point2D centerLine = new Point2D(...) ;
Point2D centerShape = new Point2D(...) ;
Point2D requiredPoint = centerLine.multiply(1-coeff).add(centerShape.multiply(coeff));
```

As noted, you can get the center of the line simply as the average of the endpoints and the center of the shape as the average of the vertexes.

Here is a demo:

```
package com.example.vectors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polyline;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    private Point2D centerLine ;
    private Point2D centerShape;

    private Circle point = new Circle(5);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Spinner<Integer> numVertexesSpinner = new Spinner<>(3, 10, 5);
        Slider pointSlider = new Slider(0, 1, 0.5);
        VBox controls = new VBox(5, numVertexesSpinner, pointSlider);
        Pane drawingPane = new Pane();
        drawingPane.setPrefSize(420, 420);
        drawShapes(numVertexesSpinner.getValue(), pointSlider.getValue(), drawingPane);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(controls);
        root.setCenter(drawingPane);

        numVertexesSpinner.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) ->
                drawShapes(newValue, pointSlider.getValue(), drawingPane)
        );

        pointSlider.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValues, newValue)  -> updatePoint(newValue.doubleValue()));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void drawShapes(int numVertexes, double pointPos, Pane pane) {
        pane.getChildren().clear();
        final double radius = 200 ;
        Point2D[] vertexes =  new Point2D[numVertexes];
        double[] coords = new double[numVertexes * 2 + 2];
        for (int i = 0 ; i<vertexes.length; i++) {
            double angle = 2 * Math.PI * i / numVertexes;
            double x = radius + radius * Math.cos(angle);
            double y = radius + radius * Math.sin(angle);
            vertexes[i] = new Point2D(x, y);
            coords[2*i] = x ;
            coords[2*i+1] = y ;
        }
        coords[numVertexes * 2] = coords[0];
        coords[numVertexes * 2 + 1] = coords[1];
        Polyline poly = new Polyline(coords);
        pane.getChildren().add(poly);
        centerLine = vertexes[0].add((vertexes[1])).multiply(0.5);
        centerShape = new Point2D(0,0);
        for (Point2D vertex : vertexes) {
            centerShape = centerShape.add(vertex);
        }
        centerShape = centerShape.multiply(1.0 / numVertexes);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(new Circle(centerLine.getX(), centerLine.getY(), 5));
        pane.getChildren().addAll(new Circle(centerShape.getX(), centerShape.getY(), 5));
        pane.getChildren().add(point);
        updatePoint(pointPos);
    }

    private void updatePoint(double pointPos) {
        Point2D pos = centerLine.multiply(1-pointPos).add(centerShape.multiply(pointPos));
        point.setCenterX(pos.getX());
        point.setCenterY(pos.getY());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be better on Mathmatics on StackExchange.

But I think this is how to do it (will only work for eqilateral triangle)

1. Calculate the midpoint of your polygon: You can calculate the midpoint as the average of all the vertexes
2. Calculate the point at which the text should be drawn: This is tricky, as where the line should start depends on the FontMetrics height. And fitting the text into the space depends on the FontMetrics.charWidth. Thus, I think the calculation for this is a differential equation (or you could just go with test and adjust iteratively)

Honestly this is a very tricky problem that will only work with this unique shape. Is this worth it to you?

Again, I recommend you try Mathematics to see if they have a better answer.

Comment: Its not the full Mathematics problem and can done with java it self. for that I wrote it here. number one done number two, gap I added it's for FontMetrics but nearing two point2d that have angle from center It's Problem that found here.(nearing center of line into center of shape)

Comment: Yep  Is this worth for me.and thanks for helping me

Comment: Note the [`Point2D`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/geometry/Point2D.html) class provides all the vector functionality you need. Given `Point2D start` and `Point2D center` you can do `Point2D needed = center.add(start.subtract(center).multiply(coeff));`